# certain drupal modules not working

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've installed drupal several times and I'm still having the same problem. Some modules aren't working.

E.g:

[Admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) - They don't always appear. It only shows in random moments.

[Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg/) and CKeditor - is not visible when I'm creating the content.

These are the modules I have installed and I'm using Marinelli theme:

- admin menu
- Wysiwyg
- IMCE Wysiwyg bridge
- IMCE - this is for images
- IMCE Mkdir
- Pathauto
- Chaos tools
- insert
- Mega menu

Comment: just to confirm, did you set the editor for any of the Input format such as Filtered HTML and Full HTML in Administer >> Site Configuration >> Wysiwyg Profiles (admin/settings/wysiwyg/)?

Comment: The modules you mention all need JavaScript to work. Check in your browser if you have JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a JQuery version conflict. Do you have the JQuery Update module? Or did you include some script not compatible with Drupal's version of JQuery?

Comment: No I dont have the JQuery update module. Should I install it? and forgive me but I'm just a newbie but I really like this cms.

Comment: Yeah, try that module and see if your problem is solved. That's usually the first thing I install.